# No export dialog on QGIS 2.8 and 2.10 with Mac OS X Yosemite?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I'm trying to work out the map making tutorial here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

When I try to export an image or pdf or even print the map I built in the composer, I receive no response, no dialog, nothing.

I tried QGIS 2.8 and 2.10. My computer is a Mac mini with OSX Yosemite and 4GB RAM.
I couldn't find any log files to debug or anything.

Comment: I couldn't find a related bug report. Could you record a screencast of the issue or at least open a ticket on http://hub.qgis.org?

Comment: Now I could isolate the bug. The error happens when you insert a label and tick the option "Render as HTML". After that you can not export. But as soon as you uncheck that option you are able to do so again.

Comment: I've uploaded a screencast in https://youtu.be/C2QZX9iSYe8

Comment: I've found a bug report under the title "Print Composer won't export PDF" at http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13143

It's the same bug, but I added more information. I hope somebody fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: this seems to be a known issue http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13143